# Implicit cast to Func or Action delegates?

Tags: c#, casting, delegates, implicit, func

C# allows you to define an implicit cast to a delegate type:

```
class myclass
{
    public static implicit operator Func<String, int>(myclass x)
    {
        return s => 5;
    }
    public static implicit operator myclass(Func<String, int> f)
    {
        return new myclass();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, we can't use this to make an object look like a function:

```
var xx = new myclass();
int j = xx("foo");    // error
Action<Func<String, int>> foo = arg => { };
foo(xx);              // ok
```

Is there a nice way to make an object of one's own class accept function-style parameters (arguments) directly on of its base instance? Kind of like an indexer, but with parentheses instead of square brackets?

Comment: I really hope there isn't one. This would result in pretty unreadable code.

Comment: @Femaref: Actually, this is used extensively in Python to great effect.

Comment: Bad OOP design, but if you must - you CAN have indexer with your wanted parameters. If it's gonna be ugly, you might as well use '[' instead of '('.

Comment: @Femaref I'm quite late but, this is just simply not true. There's many cases in code where it would be nice to treat a function as a first class object _and_ also a function. As an example [typed callbacks](https://haxetink.github.io/tink_core/#/types/callback) (this particular language already supports functions as first class objects but that kind of adds to the point; these effectively are static extensions ontop of first class objects that are callable objects/functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C# does not allow that as part of the language. Underneath the covers, the CLI uses the `call` and `callvirt` instructions to invoke a method or, indirectly, a delegate.

So, unlike Python where you can make an instance of a class `callable` by declaring a `def __call__` method, C# has no similar feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll just wait a bit more to see if anyone has any obscure workarounds before marking as the answer.

Comment: Is this still the case as of C# 6?

Comment: @GwynBleidd Yes, CLI has changed a bit but core concepts cannot be changed as mentioned in anwser. Also, I dont think we will see this functionality any time in C#.

Comment: Is this still the case as of C# 7.1?

Comment: @shtse8 Yes.  And 8. And 9.  And 10...